# lme4 - maximum number of function evaluations exceeded

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, convergence

I run a simple GLMM with lme4 ...

```
model1  <- glmer.nb(S ~ Days*Grazing*Biome + (Days|Site), data=mydata, verbose=T, control=ctrl)
```

...and run into the convergence code 1 from bobyqa: "bobyqa -- maximum number of function evaluations exceeded". So I looked up stackoverflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999329/control-maximum-number-of-iterations-in-lme4-1-0) interesting thread.

I overhauled my control object which now looks like this:

```
ctrl = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa",
                    #restart_edge=T,
                    boundary.tol = 1e-5,
                    calc.derivs=TRUE,
                    use.last.params=FALSE,
                    sparseX = FALSE,
                    tolPwrss=1e-7,
                    compDev=TRUE,
                    nAGQ0initStep=TRUE, 
                    ## optimizer args
                    optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e5))
```

But I still get the same error. Then I followed the adivse of another [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2014q2/022084.html) where it is said that

- you can use control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e5)) to adjust
  the maximum number of function evaluations.  **CHECK**
- if @optinfo$feval will tell you how many function evaluations were
  actually used. **TBD**

So I did model1@optinfo$feval  and it says ... **172**

I must admit that I was expecting something else, so I tried everything from 1e3 to 1e8 but I am still stuck.

My lme4 version is 1.1-10; I am using a Win10 64bit R3.1.3  (maybe I should upgrade my R?)

Any (!) help or comments are most appreciated! 
cheers

Comment: What happens if you use a different optimizer?

Comment: setting optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1)) ... leads to  --> model1.s@optinfo$feval = 7535    why ?

Comment: @Dason when I switch to Nelder_Mead I yield "1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0809893 (tol = 0.001, component 1)"  but I will try some others, thanks for that idea !

Comment: How big is your total parameter vector (fixed effects + random effects)?  I wonder if the distinction is between BOBYQA iterations and actual function evaluations.  (Having just checked the BOBYQA source code, that doesn't seem to be the case though ...)

Comment: any chance of  a reproducible example ... ??

Comment: @Ben hmm how do I know how big the parameter vector is? I fear it is hard to make the example reproducable, but I will try .

Comment: assuming `Days` is numeric and not a factor, `ncol(model.matrix(~Days*Grazing*Biome, data=mydata))+2` should be about right ... (the fixed effects vector length is the product of the number of parameters per input variable, which is 2 for a numeric variable or n for a factor ...)

Comment: (if `Days` were a factor instead that could make the model very big ...)

Comment: The answer is: 18   Days is indeed numeric.

Comment: @Dason I also tried optimx with nlminb etc. nothing helped.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe this is a `glmer.nb` bug where the controls don't get passed through to the optimizer properly.  What  happens if you fit a Poisson model with the same structure?

Comment: @BenBolker works fine with poisson and took 5 seconds. I could live with poisson as well, but fitdistr showed me that poisson did not fit the species richness data well at all.

Comment: OK, it's probably a `glmer.nb` bug.  Are you willing to send me data?

Comment: @BenBolker Sure, will do. Thank you very much for your help already!

Comment: I am very interested by the outcome of your research. What came out of your investigation ?